# Log something in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a tic tac toe game in jquery, but have run into a problem. I want to log the location of every click each player makes in an array. When I use console.log to check if the log was made, it shows me that it was. but after the game if i check the array, its all filled with either 1s or 2s, when it should be full of a combination of both.(1 means player ones choice, 2 means player twos.) I was thinking you guys might be able to help me.

```
var playerTurn = 1;
var counter = 0;
var gamArr = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        if (playerTurn == 1) {
            if (this.classList == "player1" || this.classList == "player2") {
            }
            else {
                $(this).toggleClass('player' + playerTurn, true);
                playerTurn = 2;
                counter++;
                var myCol = $(this).index();
                var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var myRow = $tr.index();
                gamArr[myRow[myCol]] = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (this.classList == "player1" || this.classList == "player2") {
            }
            else {
                $(this).toggleClass('player' + playerTurn, true);
                playerTurn = 1;
                counter++;
                var myCol = $(this).index();
                var myRow = $(this).closest('tr').index();
                gamArr[myRow[myCol]] = 2;
            }
        }
        if (counter >= 9) {
        }
    });
});
```

here is the jsfiddle page: 
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lukabuz/ccpcxzL3/17/)

gamArr is the array in question.

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you want to get the sum of all elements for each array?

Comment: Please, share an example of final array(s) that you want

Comment: for example, if the table looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/DZYhSlw.png), the array/matrix should be [[1,2,1],[2,1,2],[1,2,1]]. 1= red player, 2= blue player. I want to have this array/matrix so I can check who won the game at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access slightly different to your sub-arrays. You were close. Here is the fix:

```
gamArr[myRow][myCol] = 1; //or 2
```

myRow - index of sub-array, myCol, index of element.

change all your logs according to this: https://jsfiddle.net/ccpcxzL3/27/